# Qiskit package installed locally, but not running in jupyter notebook

Tags: programming, qiskit

I believe I have installed qiskit on my computer. Running pip list or pip3 list in terminal returns:

```
qiskit                   0.26.0
qiskit-aer               0.8.2
qiskit-aqua              0.9.1
qiskit-ibmq-provider     0.13.1
qiskit-ignis             0.6.0
qiskit-terra             0.17.3
```

However when I then open a jupyter notebook and try

```
import qiskit
```

I get told that there is no module named qiskit available. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I had the same problem, and the below answer didn't work for me. Instead, I found another answer here on StackExchange that solved this issue: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15591/15981

I'm new to all this, so forgive me if I butcher the explanation, but basically Jupyter is not starting a kernel within your new environment you made for QISKIT, so you need to set it up to give you the option to create notebooks within that environment.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer on the Qiskit slack channel and thought I would post here in case someone else comes across the same issue. I did not have jupyter installed in the same environment where Qiskit was installed. Just running `pip install jupyter` and restarting the terminal worked for me.